# Cannot figure out how to evaluate series subscript

Tags: pine-script

Can someone please help me to understand the following piece of code?
Ok, so I'm checking hlc3 on a Swedish stock and plotting the result from an XSA function found in one strat on tradeview. I understand series and how that easily can be confused by arrays.
Now to the point, my input src (hlc3)

```
src = 720.7
variable ma, still = 720.7 
but variable b[1] changed it to 59...
```

where does 59 come from?

```
xsa(src,len,wei) =>

    sumf = 0.0
    ma = 0.0
    out = 0.0
    b = 0.0
    sumf  :=  nz(sumf[1]) - nz(src[len]) + src

    ma  :=  na(src[len]) ? na : sumf/len

    b := na(b[1]) ? ma : b[1]
    b[1]

al = hlc3

plotchar(xsa(al,1,1), "Bar Index", "", location = location.top)
```

[Image from tradeview with value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDZXg.png)

Answer (score 0):

`src` should not be a value, instead it should be an array.

Let me try to put into this way:

```
sumf = 0 + 720.7
ma = 720.7/1 = 720.7
```

After the calculation above, the `ma` and `sumf` also return an array, so when `b` try to access the `ma` array `b[1]`, the array of previous current bar value is 59.